# Mosaic Decisions Azure BLOB writer node creating multiple files

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I’m using mosaic decisions data flow feature to read a file from Azure blob, do a few transformations and write that data back to Azure. It worked fine except that in the output file path I have given, it created a folder and I can see many files with some strange “part-000” etc in their names. What I need is a single file in that output location – Not many. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mosaic-Decisions uses apache spark as its backend execution engine. In Spark, the dataframe read is split into multiple partitions and these partitions are written to the output location in parallel. That's the reason it creates multiple files at the target location with "part-0000", "part-0001" etc. (part here represents partition).

The workaround on this is to check "combine-output-files-into-one" in writer node. This will combine all of the part files into one big file. But use this with caution and only if you really need a single file - as this will come with a performance tradeoff.